# How to fix this error on FER system that i would like to develop?

Tags: python

IDK how to fix this code for my system.(Facial Expression Recognition) i followed this youtube video for solution[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHdrxHPRBng&t=227s&ab_channel=DataMagic%28bySunnyKusawa%29) but still does't work. it really help me to find the solution

This is the code

```
# import required packages
import cv2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Initialize image data generator with rescaling
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Preprocess all test images
train_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# Preprocess all train images
validation_generator = validation_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test',
        target_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# create model structure
emotion_model = Sequential()

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

emotion_model.add(Flatten())
emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the neural network/model
emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=28709 // 64,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=7178 // 64)

# save model structure in jason file
model_json = emotion_model.to_json()
with open("emotion_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# save trained model weight in .h5 file
emotion_model.save_weights('emotion_model.h5')
```

This is the error

```
Found 15991 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 7178 images belonging to 7 classes.
C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\adam.py:114: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 52
     49 emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
     51 # Train the neural network/model
---> 52 emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit(
     53         train_generator,
     54         steps_per_epoch=28709 // 64,
     55         epochs=10,
     56         validation_data=validation_generator,
     57         validation_steps=7178 // 64)
     59 # save model structure in jason file
     60 model_json = emotion_model.to_json()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
```

Comment: Code format the error to make readable. Also post the new error.

Comment: The docs don't show any postional arguments for Sequential.fit - only keyword arguments. You passed a positional argument, `train_generator,`.

Comment: what do you mean I don't understand about the positional arguments

Comment: Well, maybe that was wrong anyway. I was just trying to compare your call to the documentation. There are a few Q&A's searching with `InvalidArgumentError site:stackoverflow.com` - maybe they will give you a clue.